# Two databases and various entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

How can I associate two entities, each in a different database.
I have created two entity manager one for each database, default and customer_1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot associate entities in different databases, at least not in the latest Doctrine version.

Moreover this is not advisable as the underlying database server (ie. MySQL) will not be able to guarantee data integrity across independent databases. Foreign keys for example do not allow you to reference keys outside the parent database.

The multiple `entity managers` as envisioned by Symfony here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html are meant only for accessing different bundle sets in the same app. If you want to associate your entities you'll have to use ***one*** database.

Comment: Actually if you specify the database name as part of the table name(database_name.table_name) when mapping your entities, then D2 can indeed associate across databases as long as they are on the same server.  Not recommended but it works.  I was going to down vote because the answer is wrong but the advice is good.

Comment: @Cerad this would only apply for databases which share the same connection as the used D2 instance. D2 instances have only one connection, thus your solution would not work for databases located on different nodes. Moreover the since the official documentation does not mention this possibility (see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-table) this hack would not be sustainable and possibly not work in newer releases.